# Is there a way to do a loop in R studio like in Stata

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

I need to create a variable by summing other variables. I need to create

```
Output_total=Output_manufacturing+Output_agriculture
Prices_total=Prices_manufacturing+Prices_agriculture
```

I would do it like smth like

```
global var "Output Prices"
foreach v of global var {
g `var'_Total=`var'_manufacturing +`var'_Agriculture
}
```

I am trying to do

```
 var <- c("Output","Prices")
for (i in length(var)) {
  data<-data %>% mutate( as.numeric(paste(data, i,"_Total"))= as.numeric(paste(data, i,"_manufacturing"))+ as.numeric(paste(data, i,"_agriculture"))) }
```

But it does not work. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Toy data:

```
set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame(Output_manufacturing = runif(5),
                   Output_agriculture   = runif(5),
                   Prices_manufacturing = runif(5),
                   Prices_agriculture   = runif(5))
```

I think what you're trying to do is this.

```
vars <- c("Output","Prices")
for (var in vars) {
 data <- data %>%
  mutate(!!sym(paste0(var, "_Total")) := 
          !!sym(paste0(var, "_manufacturing")) + 
          !!sym(paste0(var, "_agriculture")))
}

data
#>   Output_manufacturing Output_agriculture Prices_manufacturing Prices_agriculture Output_Total Prices_Total
#> 1            0.2655087         0.89838968            0.2059746          0.4976992    1.1638983    0.7036738
#> 2            0.3721239         0.94467527            0.1765568          0.7176185    1.3167992    0.8941753
#> 3            0.5728534         0.66079779            0.6870228          0.9919061    1.2336512    1.6789289
#> 4            0.9082078         0.62911404            0.3841037          0.3800352    1.5373218    0.7641389
#> 5            0.2016819         0.06178627            0.7698414          0.7774452    0.2634682    1.5472866
```

---

Another way with `dplyr` is:

```
library(dplyr)
vars <- c("Output","Prices")

data <- data %>% rowwise()

for (var in vars)
 data <- data %>% mutate("{var}_Total" := sum(c_across(starts_with(var))))

data <- data %>% ungroup()
```

---

With base R:

```
# vars you want to sum
vars <- c("Output","Prices")

# get position of the vars to sum
v <- grep(paste0("^", vars, collapse = "|"), names(data))

# sum cols
data[vars] <- lapply(split.default(data[v], sub('(.*)_.*','\\1_Total', names(data[v]))), rowSums)
```

which is flexible with the number of columns you want to sum.